# Where can i find oceanic borders defined as a set of lat/long points?

Tags: data, extents

I'm trying to write some code that, given a latitude and longitude, will report which ocean (if any) this point is in.

Is there a public resource available that defines the borders of the oceans as a set of lat/long points that I can download?

Comment: This question is I think a bit different from the other one. The resources pointed to in the accepted answer has just two polygons, one for the Caspian Sea and one for the rest of the world, whereas @Dancrumb wants to know _which_ body of water a given point lies in, e.g. North Atlantic, Bering Sea, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ESRI's Ocean Basemap might be useful for your task:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6348e67824504fc9a62976434bf0d8d5

Answer (score 1):

Ocean polygons available here:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/

or

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/

Different resolutions.  You can open the shapefiles in QGis and save as any format you want [assuming you're writing a browser based app].